# Read single observation from compressed dataset (.sas7bdat.gz)

Tags: sas

I need to run proc contents (interested in names and data types) on multiple large gzipped datasets on a machine with limited free disk space. Is it possible to read a **single observation** from the .sas7bdat.gz?

My current approach is:

```
filename zipf ZIP "/mypath/myfile.sas7bdat.gz" GZIP;
filename outf "%sysfunc(getoption(WORK))/myfile.sas7bdat";

data _null_;
  infile zipf lrecl=512 recfm=F length=length eof=eof;
    file outf lrecl=512 recfm=N;
  input;
  put _infile_ $varying512. length;
  return;
  eof: stop;
  run;
proc contents data=myfile; run;
```

Comment: I believe it has to be unzipped in order to read a zipped sas7bdat file. You can store them as compressed with the compress=yes option. You might want to give that a try to store them without needing to zip.

Comment: No.  If space is limited make sure to delete the uncompressed copy of the file after you have run the proc contents.

Comment: Your ultimate goal is to get the file layout from the file, not to read just one record? There may be a way to do that, since R can access some of this without processing everything but you may want to post to communities.sas.com for some of the more expert users to chime in.